# Setting and calling a value as a filename in R

Tags: r, bash, filenames

What I want to do is to set a value in R called "filename", with the content being the first part of a filename.

> filename <- "E14_AD_4hr_"

I then want to use this 'filename' value to both name and call vectors that will be created through an R script.

Using the bash $ , the syntax would look something like this:

> filename <- "E14_AD_4hr_"
>
> $filename_Asz1 <- read.table("~/Documents/1608_10_MiSeq/untitled folder 2/E14-AD-4_S20_L001/Filtered_by_quality/E14-AD-4_S20_L001_Asz1/methylation.tsv", quote="\"", comment.char="")
>   etc.

But this only gives me an error in R.

To get it to run the script correctly, I have to enter the first part of the filenames manually, which is a pain and very inelegant (there's more to the script, but I've only posted the first line).

> E14_AD_4hr_Asz1 <- read.table("~/Documents/1608_10_MiSeq/untitled folder 2/E14-AD-4_S20_L001/Filtered_by_quality/E14-AD-4_S20_L001_Asz1/methylation.tsv", quote="\"", comment.char="")

Basically what I'm asking is does anyone know the correct syntax to set and call a name in this way, in R?

Thanks.

Comment: If we are reading multiple files, it is better to keep them in one list. Each data object within a list named as "Asz1, Asz2, AszN". See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r)

Answer (score -2):

I believe you're looking for `assign`.

```
prefix = "E14_AD_4hr_"

var_name = sprintf("%s_Asz1", prefix)
assign(var_name, read.table(...))
```

Note that if you invoke assign inside of a function, you might have to be careful about the `environment` you insert into. You can of course always assign to `.GlobalEnv`, or you could call `parent.env()` to jump one layer in the stack frame.

If you need to call those generated names later, you likely want `parse` and `eval`. For instance, if we store 10 random numbers in your variable name:

```
prefix = "E14_AD_4hr_"

var_name = sprintf("%s_Asz1", prefix)
assign(var_name, rnorm(10))

# Get the string value back
print(var_name)
[1] "E14_AD_4hr__Asz1"

# Convert to a language expression
> print(parse(text = var_name))
expression(E14_AD_4hr__Asz1)

# Evaluate in the current frame
> print(eval(parse(text = var_name)))
 [1] -0.31945098 -0.54377885 -0.27967344  1.06523260  1.56782875 -0.64311208  0.02052175 -0.32418446
 [9]  1.85739602  0.59076400
```